# Git hosting with personal namespaces

Tags: git, hosting

I like the way that in launchpad if I want to host an app of little use to the public (like, say, a program which prints dots to the console, the count of them depending on which hour it is) I don't have to litter the global hosting site's namespace and fill it up with names such as HourDot but I can put it in my own personal namespace ~username/+junk/HourDot.

Putting all the branches without hierarchy feels like putting everything in one big directory.

Is there a git hosting site where I get to have a namespace for such small apps? Ease of creating and deleting temporary branches also interests me.

Comment: You can host your .git dir renaming it to project.git, and putting it in your user public_html directory, just remember this wont work to do a push to the repo, in other words just read only. Also remember to add the user_dirs module to apache.

You can actually do it using webdav, here is a guide, but I had many problems with it, that I switched to ssh:

http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/howto/setup-git-server-over-http.txt

Comment: Gitorious allows to have many repositories for one project, so I can put all the various little stuff into seperate repos of a non-critical project I own.

Answer (score 7):

Hosting sites such as [GitHub](https://github.com/) and [Gitorious](http://gitorious.org/) embed username or name of fork in path (name) of repository (or a fork), e.g. http://github.com/jnareb/softsnow-xchat2-filter on GitHub (with username "jnareb" embedded in the name of repository), or http://gitorious.org/softsnow-xchat2-filter/mainline on Gitorious (with name of fork "mainline" embedded in full name of repository).

Git allows arbitrary names (including deeper hierarchy) for git repositories, which can be seen in names such as http://git.kernel.org/?p=git/git.git (in `git/` "namespace").

---

**Note** that most git hosting sites (see e.g. http://git.or.cz/giwiki/GitHosting) provide *free* service for *public* repositories only.